# If statement is rendering to screen

Tags: templates, template-scripting

I am trying to check if a variable exists, and render it only if it does.  Using the code below, the "{if facebook_content..." etc renders to the screen, curley braces and all, rather than actually checking for this conditional.  Its like it doesn't get processed at all.  Why is this happening and how can I actually do this?

```
    {exp:stash:get_list name="st_facebook_feed_list" parse_tags="yes" process="end"}
                <a target="_blank" href="{facebook_url}">
                    <span class="feed-text">
                        {if facebook_content != ''}
                            {facebook_content}
                        {/if}
                    </span>
                </a>
    {/exp:stash:get_list}
```

Answer (score 1):

I beleive you can get some info from this ist : https://gist.github.com/croxton/9d012297096892ca5c10

The premise is the insides of the stash tag is parsed at the stage the module tags are parse, whereas conditionals are passed before (simple) and after (advanced).

Have you tried messing about with [`{exp:stash:parse}`](https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/%7Bexp:stash:parse%7D) inside the `get_list` tag pair?

Also, what are your results when you call `get_list` without the `process="end"` parameter? I believe this may move the parsing of the inard of your tag to after all the conditional steps, ergo no evaluation. Of course you don't show us where you set the list so I couldn't debug the parse order any further.